# Replace Backslashes with Forward Slashes in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a cross platform file explorer in python. I am trying to convert any backslashes in a path into forward slashes in order to deal with all paths in one format.

I've tried not only using string.replace(str, '\\', '/'), but also creating a method manually to search through the string and replace the instances, and both do not work properly, as a path name such as:

```
\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more
```

changes to:

```
/dir/anotherdir\x0oodir/more
```

I am assuming that this has something to do with how Python represents escape characters or something of the sort. How do I prevent this happening?

Comment: `r'\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more'.replace('\\', '/')` works just fine.

Comment: Your error occurs because you typed `\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more` as a string yourself, and `\f` is special. If you want Python not to interpret special characters (characters prefixed by backslashes) you should use “raw” strings, e.g: `r'\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more'`

Comment: `os.path.abspath` will convert them to unified format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) for this kind of stuff. In Python 3, you can also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to represent paths in a portable manner, so you don't have to worry about things like slashes anymore.

Comment: I cannot see any functions in os.path related to replacing backslashes with forwardslashes. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The functions in `os.path` are designed so you don't have to care what kind of slashes your paths contain. E.g. if you use `os.path.join` to join paths, it will use the appropriate separator for your platform.

Comment: Thanks, so just to be clear there are no functions in os.path that actually replace slashes, just functions that allow you to avoid dealing with path separators.

Comment: This question was about how to replace backslashes not how to join files.

Answer (score 32):

Elaborating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119176/),
with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can use the [as_posix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) method:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r'\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more')
>>> print(p)    
\dir\anotherdir\foodir\more
>>> print(p.as_posix())
/dir/anotherdir/foodir/more
>>> str(p)
'\\dir\\anotherdir\\foodir\\more'
>>> str(p.as_posix())
'/dir/anotherdir/foodir/more'
```

Answer (score 13):

Doesn't this work:

```
    >>> s = 'a\\b'
    >>> s
    'a\\b'
    >>> print s
    a\b
    >>> s.replace('\\','/')
    'a/b'
```

?

EDIT:

Of course this is a string-based solution, and using *os.path* is wiser if you're dealing with filesystem paths.