# How to replace backslash with forward slash - Python

Tags: python, file, escaping, backslash

I wrote this simple little program:

```
def main ( ):
    with open("test.txt", "rt") as fin:
        with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
                for line in fin:
                    fout.write(line.replace("\", "/"))
    print ("done")
main ()
```

I know that "" is an escape literal in Python but all I need is to scan through the text file and replace every single backlash with a forward slash "/".

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Maybe use "\\" instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Backslashes with Forward Slashes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119166/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that strings in python are interpreted. Only raw strings do not follow this rule. Here I mean that if for example you have a `"\n"` included in your string, it would be interpreted as a new line. 
Fortunately strings read from file are already raw.

All you have to do is simply use the regular expression:

```
s.replace('\\','/')
```

Comment: Thank you! that seems to solve the issue I was having.

Comment: You know how to replace '\"' by 'somestring' as in ...
     'hello \" to replace'.replace('\"', '\\"') ...
This does not seem to work.

Comment: Use cascade of replacements:
`'hello \" to replace'.replace('\\', '').replace('"', '')`