# Python 3 pywin32 saveAs funtion with tkinter GUI saveas dialog path as input

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pywin32, win32com, save-as

I am a complete beginner to coding and I am having issues figuring out how to use the tkinter asksavefileasname diaglog as the path for win32 to save an open excel file.  I continue to receive;

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,
>   'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\//Users/user1/Desktop/610D1100'. There are several possible
>   reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is
>   being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save
>   has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0,
>   -2146827284)

Here is the relevant code:

```
from  tkinter import filedialog
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
if selection == 'Other':
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\template1.xlsx')

saveFile = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
                                    ("All files", "*.*") ))
print (saveFile) #This gives the correct file path

wb.SaveAs(saveFile)

excel.Application.Quit()
```

If I type in the path manually for savefile, it works without an issue.

I am trying to get user input from a saveas diaglog box to be the path where the file is saved.

ie. wb.SaveAs(#path and filename from user input in GUI)

I am not saving as a filename already open.  The correct path prints when using print(saveFile)  The only unknown is the added \ in the path from the error message. I'm not sure if this is a tkinter issue adding the \ to the path or if this is irrelevant.

Edit** I don't think this is a tkinter problem as it works with printing and it gives me a different filename in the error msg which leads me to believe this is a win32 related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was my variable being returned with / instead of \ as path separators.

wb.SaveAs only accepts \ in file paths

The solution was to use os.path as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730428/why-cant-i-save-as-an-excel-file-from-my-python-code)

For more details check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

```
saveFile = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files", "*.*") ))
saveFileNoSlash = os.path.normpath(saveFile)

wb.SaveAs(saveFileNoSlash)

excel.Application.Quit()
```

Additional information regarding issues with different slashes and replacing backslash with forward is on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119166/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-python/4119176#4119176)

Comment: Thank you for this, I spent 2 hours troubleshooting and this was the answer.