# python raises syntax error in environment variable path

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, environment-variables

I have this enviroment variable: `VAR=C:\Users\User`
but how can I prevent python giving this `"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` error when I try:

```
import os
os.environ["VAR"]
```

without needing to change the variable in Command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add r to let compiler knows it's a raw string.

> r'{}'.format(os.environ["VAR"]))

However, your code works on myside without any changes.

[image]

Comment: thanks this works and it is `C:\users\User` and that is what python does not like but this work

Answer (score 0):

The unicode error comes from the "\U". So you can also change your

```
VAR=C:\Users\User
```

to

```
VAR=C:\\Users\\User
```

so that Python recognizes the dashes as literal dashes.

Comment: is this without changing the variable? no

Comment: Sorry, did not read the last part. But it may help you to know where the SyntaxError is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the reason are the dashs. Did you try:

```
Try VAR=C:/Users/User
```

Comment: i said without changing it

Comment: This looks similar to your problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119166/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-python#4119176